# Printing User Model Attributes on the Navigation Bar

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to print the first name and company name on the navbar but it does not print anything out

base.html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-lightgrey">
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                {% if request.user.is_authenticated and request.user.is_student %}:
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto"> 
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'home' %}">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                        </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'jobs' %}">Jobs</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                {{student.first_name}}
                                </a>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">My Account</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Change Password</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </ul>
                {% elif request.user.is_authenticated and request.user.is_employer %}:
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto"> 
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'home' %}">Home<span class="sr-only(current)</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Posts</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="jobs-create">Add Jobs</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Students</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-5">
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            {{employer.company_name}}
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">My Account</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Change Password</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        </ul>
                    </ul>
                {% else %}:
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto"> 
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'home' %}">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                        </li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                Register
                                </a>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" style="min-width: 3rem;">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'employee-register' %}">Employee</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'employer-register' %}">Employer</a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </ul>
                {% endif %}
            </div>      
        </nav>
```

model.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, blank=False)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_employer = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='student_profile', primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    level = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=LEVEL)
    school = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=SCHOOL)
    major = models.CharField(max_length=40, default="")
    cv = models.FileField(blank=True)
    skills_or_trainings = models.TextField(default="")
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name


class Employer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='employer_profile', primary_key=True)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    company_address = models.TextField()
    website = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=100, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.company_name
```

form.py

```
class UserRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['email']
    
    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user

class EmployeeRegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(label='First Name')
    last_name = forms.CharField(label='Last Name')
    cv = forms.FileField(label='CV')
    skills_or_trainings = forms.SlugField(label='Skills or Trainings', required=False, widget=forms.Textarea)
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'gender', 'level', 'school', 'major', 'cv', 'skills_or_trainings' ]



class EmployerRegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    company_name = forms.CharField(label="Company Name")
    company_address = forms.CharField(label="Company Address")
    website = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = Employer
        fields = ['company_name', 'company_address', 'website']
```

I don't know if I am not getting it right or there is a different way for calling the model fields in the navbar. If I use {{ user.email }} it will print out but if I use {{ student.first_name }}, it won't print anything out

Comment: I know Django has a default first_name field but if I use it, it'll only be useful for the Student field and not the Employer field because I need the Company name and Company Address to be the label. I don't know if it's possible to change the label for the Employer model to show the company name and address as the label while using the default first_name field for my Student model too

Answer (score 0):

Use `{{ user.student.first_name }}`

Comment: {{user.student.first_name}} isn't still printing anything

Comment: Then try {{ request.user.first_name }} You need to understand that django templates use context variables you've provided in your views. Without seeing views I can't tell anything.

Comment: I am not using the default Django first_name field. My first_name field is in my Student model but it isn't printing anything out when I call it

Comment: {{ request.user.first_name }} would print out only when I use the first_name provided with by the default Django User model

Comment: Your user is connected through one to one field with user, so the right way will be {{ request.user.student.first_name }}